# ディープコピーを確認する方法は？　コピー前後でオブジェクトの参照先が異なるため、比較してtrueになることはない？

Tags: javascript

**ディープコピーはどうやって確認するのでしょうか？**
・コピー前後でオブジェクトの参照先が異なるため、比較してtrueになることはない？
・ループして各プロパティの値が一致していたら、ディープコピー出来ている、と判断して良いのでしょうか？

**想定ケース**

```
JSON.parse(JSON.stringify(obj));
```

で作成されたオブジェクトがディープコピーであるかどうかを判定したいと考えています。

---

**追記**

・(npmのcloneを使用した場合などで、)「あるオブジェクト」が「別のオブジェクト」のディープコピーであることを条件分岐等で確認するにはどうすれば良いでしょうか？

```
var clone = require('clone');

var a, b;

a = { foo: { bar: 'baz' } };  // initial value of a 

b = clone(a);                 // clone a -> b 
//a.foo.bar = 'foo';            // change a 

console.log(a);               // show a 
console.log(b);

console.log(a==b); //false
console.log(a===b); //false
```

Comment: ディープコピーの何を確認したいんでしょうか。

Comment: どういうコピーをしているのか具体的な例を挙げてもらえますか？

Comment: @kaitoy。コピーした処理が、ディープコピーであるかどうかを確認したいです。

Comment: @BLUEPIXY。JSON.parse(JSON.stringify(obj));です。

Comment: [stringify](https://developer.mozilla.org/ja/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/JSON/stringify)は元と同じ表現になるとは限らない(再現できない場合がある)ことに注意して下さい。

Comment: JSだと__proto__などで循環参照があるので、どこかでやめる必要があるうえ、ベースの`Object`は絶対共有されるので、どういう用途でどの範囲か指定しないとなんとも言えない気が

Comment: 大前提として、「循環参照している場合は、ディープコピー出来ないのでしょうか？　それともJavaScriptで循環参照している場合は、ディープコピー出来ない？」

Comment: 前提としてJSON parse/stringifyは[ディープコピーを目的とした機能ではなく](http://qiita.com/seihmd/items/74fa9792d05278a2e898)、循環参照には対応しません。オブジェクトAをJSONデータにシリアライズし(stringify)、そこから復元(parse)したオブジェクトBは、結果的にAのコピーに相当するという考え方です。循環参照にも対応したディープコピー実装として、例えば[clone](https://www.npmjs.com/package/clone)などが挙げられます。

Comment: 質問追記しました。知りたいことは、二つのオブジェクトがある時、ディープコピーされたものか条件分岐する方法です

Comment: 追記されたコードの場合、 `a.foo.bar = 'foo'` を実行した時点で「bはaのディープ**コピー**」とは言えないというか、「bはaと同じ構造の別オブジェクト」としか言えないように思います。正しくディープコピーされたことを検証したいのか、同じ構造であることを検証したいのか、それとも過去に `clone()` によってコピーされたものであることを識別したいのか、どういうことなんでしょうか。具体的な使い道を提示してもらえるとイメージしやすいかもしれません。

Comment: a.foo.bar = 'foo' をコメントアウトしました。最終的にやりたいことは、正しくディープコピーされたかどうか検証したいです。質問背景は、(循環参照を含む)ディープコピーに関する単なる興味本位です。※ディープコピーが何か良くわからないため、理解するため色々試してみたい

Comment: @re9 下記の回答のコメントで、「対象のオブジェクトから作られたディープコピーであることを判定する」回答を欲しているのか、「対象のオブジェクトと同一のインスタンスでないことを判定する」回答を欲しているのか分からなくなったのですが、どちらでしょうか？追記を見ている限りでは、後者だとお見受けしたのですがどうでしょうか？

Comment: @Myaku 直接的に知りたいコードは「対象オブジェクトから作成されたディープコピーであるかどうかを判別するための条件分岐」です。ただ、本当に知りたい内容は「ディープコピー」の定義です。調べてみてもよく分からなかったので、「ディープコピー条件分岐」が分かれば「ディープコピー」の定義も分かるかな、と思い質問しました。ディープコピーすると、メモリアドレス(ポインタ)？　参照？　などは(循環参照している場合)どうなるか知りたいと興味本位で思い質問したのですが…

Comment: そういう経緯だったのですね…その経緯や質問意図を質問文に記載していただくと、伝わりやすかったのではと思います。それに条件分岐が分かればと言いますが、定義が分かるほどに条件分岐のコード（ないし内部実装）を理解するか、そこまで説明してもらわなければ、ゴールにはたどり着けないのではないでしょうか。

Answer (score 3):

ディープコピーというのは、オブジェクトへの参照を保持できる言語において、複合オブジェクトをコピーする際に、そこに含まれる子オブジェクトの参照をどうコピーするか、

- 実体はそのままに参照を複製する：シャローコピー
- 実体を複製する：ディープコピー

という程度の定義でしかありません。

実体を複製するというのは、要するに「同じものを真似して作る」ということです。

```
var a = { foo: [1, 2], bar: {x: 1} };
a.self = a;

var b = { foo: [1, 2], bar: {x: 1} };
b.self = b;
```

既存のオブジェクト a をそっくりそのまま真似して b を作りましたが、b からは a の一部分たりとも参照していません。これをプログラムで行うのがディープコピーです。

実際には実体の複製が難しいもの（JSだとクロージャなど）や、目的によっては複製したくないもの（DOMオブジェクトなど）があったり、手順も再現するのか状態だけ再現するのかといった話もあるので、**具体的に何をどうやって複製するかは様々です**。ですから、何をどう検証すれば正しいディープコピーと判断できるのかも一概には言えないわけです。

仕様がはっきりしていれば、それが全て正しく機能しているのかを順番に検証するだけです。例えばnpmのcloneライブラリにもテストコードがあります。

https://github.com/pvorb/clone/blob/master/test.js

> ループして各プロパティの値が一致していたら、ディープコピー出来ている、と判断して良いのでしょうか？

再帰的にプロパティの値を比較するということなら、考え方はあっています。ただし再帰構造はそのままだと無限ループになってしまいますし、`Object.defineProperty()` で定義したプロパティも再現するなら、プロパティの列挙・比較の方法も選ぶ必要があるでしょう。